# Robot fails to move in the Webots environment

Tags: ros, webots

I am trying to teleoperate a robot which is a forklift. The details of the robot are as follows:

- Weight 700KG
- 1 actively steered caster wheel and 2 passively steered rear wheels
- 2 passive standard wheels at forks (these 2 break sometimes after moving a little)

I was previously having some problem for [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352630/robot-model-drops-off-the-floor-after-running-the-simulation), which I resolved after this post. Later on I teleoperated the robot in by writing a controller in Webots. Now I am trying to move the robot using ROS teleoperation which is the same code as in Webots controller. I am facing a few problems.

1. The environment runs quite slow as because of the basic time step being set to 1. I changed its values to 4, 8, 16 but than the robot didn't moved at all however I can see the wheel rotating.
2. changing the basic time step sometimes breaks the robot.

For code to set the wheel velocities is by calling ROS services made available by Webots [controller](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-4-more-about-controllers-20-minutes) like: setting position to infinity and than setting the velocity commands.

Comment: [robotics.StackExchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question